# Error with easyAdminBundle : Undefined index: views

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a project with Symfony3 and I would like to add easyAdminBundle to handle my backend but I have a problem with the configuration.
I cannot get access to my backend and got this error

> Notice: Undefined index: views

```
        if ($this->request->attributes->has('easyadmin')) {
        $easyadmin = $this->request->attributes->get('easyadmin');
        $entity = $easyadmin['entity'];
        $action = $easyadmin['views'];
        $fields = isset($entity[$action]['fields']) ? $entity[$action]['fields'] : array();
        $view->vars['easyadmin'] = array(
            'entity' => $entity,
```

My AdminController.php

```
namespace FaimfonyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as BaseAdminController;

    class AdminController extends BaseAdminController
    {
        public function createNewUserEntity()
        {
            return $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->createUser();
        }

        public function prePersistUserEntity($user)
        {
            $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user, false);
        }
    }
```

My config.yml

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        - FaimfonyBundle\Entity\Restaurant
```